# Fetching different row keys from same partition by batching a table in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I have some time based data in a table which has a schema like this :

```
Timestamp |id | Name | Marks
```

- Timestamp represents data from a day per week in the year when exams
  are held. **Example** : 5 exam weeks every year for 5 students would have
  5 timestamps for same set of students.
- id is a unique key associated with each student.
- I have used the Partition Key as Timestamp ( as I am
  interested in figuring out performance of the class on an exam in a
  particular week.
- I have used the id as the row key( not important in my case as I dont use it to filter) 
  Now, in the client application, I am fetching the data by partition key (timestamp) and adding an
  additional layer to process details of every student. I am having to do this for every student in the university (which is a huge number of students.)

I am wondering if there is a better way to fetch these results(basically reduce number of calls) by batching the row keys in each call to filter by partition key ?

**Example** : Since I am looking for the data from a single week at a time, it just has one date . and that date is the partition key. Lets say there are 10000 students who appeared in an exam today. I dont want to make 10K calls to Cosmos DB to give me their marks. Instead , since we are looking at the same partition, is there a way to make <10K calls by filtering out rows that are not required?

Answer (score 0):

#### Example:

Expect that your partition key (Timestamp) value is: **A**
and your student ids are **b1,b2,b3,b4**
Now if your want to query only **A** for student **b1** and **b3** you can write:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Timestamp = 'A' AND (c.id = 'b1' OR c.id = 'b3')
```

You can also apply [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-group-by) on Timestamp if this will help in the result.

#### Receiving these values:

Via [SDK v3:](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-dotnet)

```
private async Task QueryItemsAsync()
{
    // sql query
    var sqlQueryText = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Timestamp= 'A' and (c.id = 'b1' or c.id = 'b3')";
    // also supports Linq

    var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);
    var queryResultSetIterator = this.container.GetItemQueryIterator<Exam>(queryDefinition);

    var exams = new List<Exam>();

    while (queryResultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        FeedResponse<Exam> currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
        foreach (var exam in currentResultSet)
        {
            exams.Add(exam);
        }
    }
    return exams;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin.But, querying by partition key gives me all records on the partition which will be a huge number of records in my case. I am trying to avoid that intentionally. Instead, I was trying to filter it down based on few rowkeys within a partition.
Example : Lets say that the timestamp is **A** and the rowkeys in the partition with Timestamp **A** are **b1,b2,b3,b4**, Then , by your query, I will get all of b1,2,3,4.

Comment: However, I only want to fetch **b2** and **b4**. Now, given that I am working with a massive dataset, I am trying to avoid two different calls for b2 and b4 respectively. Instead, my ask is if there is a way by which I can batch *b2* and *b4* in a single call ?

Comment: @user5566364: Sorry then I did not get it on the first read. I updated my answer